# Is there ANY sane way to have OSGI work with WebLogic10/11?

Tags: weblogic, osgi

I'm looking for a way to do it now. On the Oracle's road map they will be bring GlassFish and Weblogic closer together (OSGI will be there in 2012-ish). But what about now?

Asking this, cause WebLogic is default standard for the company, not because I'm a fan of it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not embed the OSGi framework within your WAR? Eclipse Equinox has even some examples on its wiki on how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

If this question is still relevant. Please have a look to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032214/weblogic-and-osgi) I've raised several months ago: WebLogic and OSGi. I also updated the question. Since version 12.1.2, Weblogic supports OSGi out of the box.