# WebLogic and OSGi

Tags: deployment, weblogic, osgi, bnd

Is there a way to run an OSGi container in the Weblogic Application Server? I know that it works with JBoss, Glassfish and there are possibilities to add an Equinox servlet bridge to your OSGi project (implementation of the bridge is too old). But I want something similar to JBoss/Glassfish functionality where it is very easy to deploy your OSGi environment, because there are already OSGi implementations. Most of the articels I found were very old and there are no more recent ones. Can someone help with hints or better some links?

Maybe Bnd could create a .war file for me, but how can I achieve it. I read there is a possibility. Example would be great!

**EDIT**

Just for those who still look into that case. Since version 12.1.2 Weblogic supports OSGi out-of-the-box.

Comment: Hello! thanks for the edit... however, I see that (
https://blogs.oracle.com/cloudappfoundation/entry/oracle_weblogic_server_12c_launch#_Toc311642815 ) the question:

_"Can you please comment on osgi (bundles) support for wls 12c?"_

is answered as:

_"WebLogic Server uses OSGi for internal modularization. OSGi has also been used to deliver products like Oracle Complex Event Processor (CEP) in Oracle SOA Suite from WebLogic Server. "_

that sounds a lot like "we use OSGi internally and in oracle soa suite", but leaves ambiguity on the possibility to deploy your own bundles...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd consider the [Apache Felix Http bridge](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-http-service.html#ApacheFelixHTTPService-UsingtheServletBridge). It worked a lot better for me than the ancient Equinox bridge (I messed around with it for a while, but never got it to work well), after I switched to Felix I got something working pretty quickly.

If I understand you correctly, you want to make a 'plain' war file, that can be deployed in any Java EE server. If that's the case, there is nothing OSGi about your war file, so I don't think Bnd will do anything for you.

Comment: Hi Frank! Thx for reply. In the same minute you wrote me I found the Felix bridge ^^ I do not want a 'plain' war file. Im using OSGi for my whole backend system and have now the requirement to run it in an application/web server. In JBoss and Glassfish its easy, because they have a Felix runtime by default and you can add bundles via hot deploy. But I also have to evaluate WebLogic and I am looking for something similar to what JBoss/Glassfish is doing. In the best case I do not need a bridge, but Im afraid that there is no other way in case of WebLogic.

Comment: As far as I know (?), WebLogic doesn't natively support OSGi. If that's the case, you're stuck with some kind of 'bridge'. I use the Felix bridge in combination with Felix fileinstall, so I basically have hot deploy in Tomcat or any other J2EE server. It works pretty well, although a 'real' OSGi server is prettier.

Comment: And have a look at Eclipse Virgo, that also sits 'between' J2EE and OSGi

Comment: Do you use the example bridge from Felix repo? Or do you have any kind of link to more information about it?

Comment: I didn't find much. I based it on the example, but needed to modify it a bit because some parts of my app couldn't run inside OSGi, so I needed to share some info across the 'OSGi boundary'. In the end, you just register a webcontextlistener that starts and stops the OSGi container, and you save that container in a ContextAttribute. There are a few subtleties but that's about it.

Comment: Thx a lot. I will just try the example of Felix bridge. Hopefully that is what you mean with "WebContextListener", but they called it "StartupListener" :)

Answer (score 0):

WebLogic now supports OSGi in version 12.1.2 . See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLPRG/osgi.htm)

Comment: Hi Abid. Thanks for your comment. I already updated my very first post with the same information ;)