# Embedding OSGi on Weblogic Server 10.3.3

Tags: osgi, weblogic, equinox

I am new to OSGi, and trying to configure Equinox/Felix on Weblogic Server. But nowhere can I find any information of any OSGi container embedded in Weblogic Server. So my questions are-

1. Has anyone configured Equinox or Felix with Weblogic Server? Is it supported?

2. SpringDM supports tomcat and jetty, does it support Weblogic too?

3. Can I deploy a Spring MVC application as a bundle without using SpringDM? OSGi container could be Felix/Equinox; and app server is Weblogic 10.3.3

Appreciate any help/samples/references to understand OSGi support in Weblogic.

Thanks in advance

-dee

Answer (score 0):

please have a look to this question I've raised several months ago: [WebLogic and OSGi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032214/weblogic-and-osgi). I also updated the question. Since version 12.1.2, Weblogic supports OSGi out of the box.